# Sporadic Connection timeout error to RDS from Laravel code

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, eloquent

We are using laravel on EC2 and connecting to an RDS instance. Sporadically, once every two days or so there is a timeout issue on the app hosted on EC2 with an error stating

```
SQLState[HY000][2002] Connection timeout error
```

There are other posts where this is due to the wrong RDS configuration but this is not the case here. The code works well for the most part. Just fails once every two days or so. Even this is not consistent. There are very few users using the system only 2 to 3 at this point. When this connection error appears the RDS instance seems to be working normally and shows no signs of any errors. We need to reboot the EC2 server for it to work again.

All of our classes extend model and just use basic queries like

```
Customer::where('type', 'example')->firstOrFail();
```

The confusing part is that it works perfectly well most of the time but just fails sporadically. We just have 2 users using the laravel app so its not a scaling issue. Wondering if it has something to do with increasing pooling limits or connection timeouts. If nothing works we would have to build a new EC2 instance to see if this occurs there as well. We do query external API's in some of our calls but that should technically have nothing to do with the RDS timeout.

Comment: I think you're fixating on infrastructure and not focusing primarily on a thorough code audit for any hidden bugs that could lead to certain queries under certain circumstances to simply take too long and cause the timeout. Also check if those timeouts happen during maintenance windows. Usually if you have ec2 communicate to rds in the same VPC and configure the connection to be strictly within the VPC then this issues would not occur except in the extremely rare event of hardware failure. Every 2 weeks or so sounds too frequent for hardware failures though

Comment: The query that fails is not a particular one. Its a different query every time.  And most of these are very simple indexed single selects. The code is real simple.  Any place where we can increase timeouts to check?

Comment: Ok most important is to ensure your database is in the same VPC and does not create a public IP address. That will ensure all connections from EC2 must happen internally. You can also monitor your database for key metrics at around the time the failures happen . Things like a large number of connections or a high CPU usage might cause subsequent connections to time out. That means that the actual issue is probably not the queries that fail but the queries that came before the one that failed. It's also good to check the EC2 instance metrics to see if there's anything odd.